# Dynamic callback url with omniauth strategies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, omniauth

In my project im using omniauth-facebook(g+) gems to provide users with ability to create accoutns in 1 click. However after user signed in into facebook(g+) he's being redirected to callback url. In my case it looks like `www.example.com/users/omniauth_callbacks/facebook`

facebook actions looks like

```
def facebook
@user = User.find_by_email(ENV['omniauth'].email)
if @user
sign_in @user
redirect_to root_path
else
create_user_account(ENV['omniauth'])
end
```

But instead of redirect_to root_path i'd like to return user back to page where he called sign_in process. I tried to user redirect_to :back, but this throws me error with empty HTTP_REFERRER. Is there any other way to track controller and action before user start sign_in process and then store it and use after callback?

Answer (score 0):

Omniauth itself doesn't provide any instrument to do so. However, you can implement something fairy simple by yourself. For example, you can store current url in cookie/session and redirect to it in your `facebook` method. Here's a similar answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595969/omniauth-redirect-to-page-which-requires-authentication-instead-of-the-one-whic).

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question. THere is piece of hash, that contains this information. Its stored in 
`request.env['omniauth.origin']`